# db4o How to rename class via configuration

Tags: c#, .net, db4o

I am using db4o in two seperate projects that share the same classes but not the same .dll . I am fixing this so that they share the same .dll but I need to rename the classes.  According to the documentation you set up configuration and open the db with the renames and it updates everything.  I have tried this but when I try to open the DB the project just hangs.  Am I missing something here

```
    config.Common.ObjectClass("DllName.Old, DllName")
    .Rename("NewDll.New, NewDll");

    var db = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(config, DBFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct to me and should work. It really should work when the class-names and assembly names are correct. The class is not a generic class, right?

You don't get any exception, right? Is db4o just hanging or actually doing some work?

Edit: I could reproduce a stack-overflow exception with renaming a class. Maybe you are running into a stack overflow exception as well, but you cancel it before it actually happens?

Anyway, I created a bug-entry in the db4o-bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful with the following answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1138178/541420

Very buggy otherwise though :(